# error while installing perl-Moose on red hat linux

Tags: redhat, perl

I am seeing the errors below while installing perl-moose using command yum install perl-Moose

Can someone please help me with commands on how to install these dependencies?
Thanks in advance

```
Error: Package: perl-Moose-2.1005-1.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: perl(Dist::CheckConflicts) >= 0.02
Error: Package: perl-Eval-Closure-0.08-4.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: perl(Sub::Exporter)
Error: Package: perl-Sub-Exporter-Progressive-0.001011-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: perl(Sub::Exporter)
Error: Package: perl-Moose-2.1005-1.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: perl(Sub::Exporter)
Error: Package: perl-Moose-2.1005-1.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: perl(Sub::Exporter) >= 0.980
Error: Package: perl-Devel-PartialDump-0.15-8.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: perl(Sub::Exporter)
```

My linux and Perl version is as below

```
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.6 (Maipo)"
```

This is perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3) built for x86_64-linux

Comment: Have you enabled `epel` on the machine?

Comment: @choroba yes epel is enabled. I removed perl and reinstalled in using yum --enablerepo=epel install perl . I still have the same error. The installed version is still v5.16.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The missing packages are in the RHEL optional channel, which you need to enable first.

```
subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-7-server-optional-rpms
```

When using RHEL on AWS, enable it this way instead:

```
yum-config-manager --enable rhui-REGION-rhel-server-optional
```

Comment: Wow, thats amazing. I spent the whole day trying to get this working. Thanks for the AWS way to enable this (this is exactly what I needed)